# javascript dom innerhtml scrollheight performance

Tags: javascript, performance, dom, innerhtml

My question is two part:

### Part1 of the question:

test a:

```
    t1 = new Date().getTime();
    for (i=0; i<205; i++) {
        document.getElementById("divTest").innerHTML = sText;

    }           
    t2 = new Date().getTime();
    alert(t2-t1);
```

result: 16ms

test b;

```
    document.getElementById("divTest").innerHTML = sText;
    t1 = new Date().getTime();
    for (i=0; i<205; i++) {         
        if ( document.getElementById("divTest").scrollHeight > document.getElementById("divTest").clientHeight ) {
            j++;
        }
    }           
    t2 = new Date().getTime();
    alert(t2-t1);
```

result: 2ms

So theoretically if we put both inside the loop we should get around: 18 ms, but test c proves me wrong:

test c:

```
    t1 = new Date().getTime();      
    for (i=0; i<205; i++) {
        document.getElementById("divTest").innerHTML = sText;       
        if ( document.getElementById("divTest").scrollHeight > document.getElementById("divTest").clientHeight ) {
            j++;
        }
    }           
    t2 = new Date().getTime();
    alert(t2-t1);
```

result : 240ms

a staggering 240ms!!! The behaviour is consistent among browsers. Why does this happen ?

### Part 2 of the question:

since

```
document.getElementById("divTest").innerHTML = sText;
```

is generally slow, i found here a faster way: http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/faster-than-innerhtml and thus the final implementation ( test c ) becomes :

```
    t1 = new Date().getTime();      
    for (i=0; i<205; i++) {
        el = document.getElementById("divTest").cloneNode(false);
        el.innerHTML = sText;
        document.getElementById("divTest").parentNode.replaceChild(el, document.getElementById("divTest"));
        if (el.scrollHeight > el.clientHeight) {
            j++;
        }
    }           
    t2 = new Date().getTime();
    alert(t2-t1);
```

with a result of 105ms which is better than 240ms

However I was wondering if through parentnode or some other way of dom manipulation i can get a faster way of accessing scrollheight and clientheight just like i replaced innerHTML with direct DOM manipulation ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you're interested in performance, why are you making the browser repeat the `getElementById("divTest")` all the time? That's a query into something that's likely to be some kind of binary tree; why not do it **once** and keep a reference to the result?

Comment: i tried setting obj = getElementById("divTest") once and then using obj but i found no difference in performance

Comment: @ Mirror: Then you must be doing this on a page with very few elements with `id`s. Fundamentally, if you can avoid a tree lookup, avoid a tree lookup. Besides, the code gets shorter and easier to read.

Comment: yes no more than 50 elements with ids

Answer (score 3):

1. When you change the `innerHTML`, the browser has to recalculate the DOM. However, if you change the `innerHTML` multiple times it can optimise by not recalculating the DOM until it needs to. Hence it takes a significantly shorter amount of time than it otherwise would. However, when you access the `scrollHeight` it needs the updated DOM, so it has to stop and recalculate every time.
2. You can optimise far better by caching the element you are modifying. `var div = document.getElementById('divTest')` and then use `div` to refer to the element. Aside from that, you are still having the barrier of recalcuating the DOM every time. Overall though, you shouldn't have this kind of thing iterating 200+ times like that, and even if you do anything less than half a second is not devastating.

Comment: 1. understood, thanks alot

2. i have to, because i'm making a pagination system based on div height and i need it as fast as possible for the case when the user resizes his window, i need to recalculate how much content fits in the resized div. p.s. yes i tried that var div = blahblah, and then using it as an object but found no difference in performance